# Using feature vector .mat file for LIBSVM in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I'm new to matlab as well as LIBSVM. I calculated feature vector for every point stating r,g,b values of point in single vector and stored it in `.mat` file. Currently I'm having around 420 points and 4 classes viz Red/Green/Blue/Other. Now I want to pass this .mat file to train libsvm and based on that classify the newly arriving test point, whether it is red or blue or green or other. Need not to mention, its a multiclass classification and I don't even know how to deal with it ?
`svmtrain(TrainingSet,Groups,'kernel_function','rbf');` where `TrainingSet` is my `420*4` feature vector set and `Groups` is class name.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? what did you try, where did you get stuck? did you read `doc svmtrain`?

Comment: LIBSVM comes with multiclass classification out of the box. Check out the documentation.